# Why doesn't the javascript for this page work on Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I created [this page](https://roceteer.com/resolution_generator) as part of an answer to another question, and didn't spend much time on it, but I noticed that it doesn't appear to load on Mobile Safari or Chrome on iOS. I did some research on here and other places and found that onclick/ontap may be at fault for mobile, but It still doesn't explain why it doesn't load the script at all in the first place.

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, I've just been looking at it too long.

Here's the relevant html & javascript code:

```
<div class="inner cover">
<h1 id="name" class="cover-heading"></h1>
<p class="lead">
<a onclick="generate()" class="btn btn-secondary">Discard</a>
<a onclick="like()" class="btn btn-secondary">Like</a>
</p>
</div>

<h5>Liked:</h5>  
<ul id="likes" class="list-unstyled"></ul>


var adjs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
var nouns = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

function generate() {
var aIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * adjs.length);
var nIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)
var adj = adjs[aIndex];
var noun = nouns[nIndex];

var name = adj + " " + noun;

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
}

function like() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
var li = document.createElement("li");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://roceteer.com/resolution_generator&amp;hashtags=resolutions2016%20&amp;text=" + name.replace(/\s+/g, '%20');
var content = document.createTextNode(name);
a.appendChild(content);
li.appendChild(a);
var ul = document.getElementById("likes");
ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstChild);
generate();
}

generate();
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
e = e || window.event;

var charCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

if (e.keyCode == '37') {
generate();
} else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
like();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with registering onclick events in browsers running on iOS. To fix this issue please try:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div class="inner cover">
<h1 id="name" class="cover-heading"></h1>
<p class="lead">
<a id="1" class="btn btn-secondary">Discard</a>
<a id="2" class="btn btn-secondary">Like</a>
</p>
</div>

<h5>Liked:</h5>  
<ul id="likes" class="list-unstyled"></ul>


var adjs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
var nouns = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

function generate() {
var aIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * adjs.length);
var nIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)
var adj = adjs[aIndex];
var noun = nouns[nIndex];

var name = adj + " " + noun;

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
}

function like() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
var li = document.createElement("li");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://roceteer.com/resolution_generator&amp;hashtags=resolutions2016%20&amp;text=" + name.replace(/\s+/g, '%20');
var content = document.createTextNode(name);
a.appendChild(content);
li.appendChild(a);
var ul = document.getElementById("likes");
ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstChild);
generate();
}

generate();
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
e = e || window.event;

var charCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

if (e.keyCode == '37') {
generate();
} else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
like();
} 
}
$('#1').on('click touchstart',function(){
generate();
});
$('#2').on('click touchstart',function(){
like();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately, even with that it still doesn't run the script. :/

Comment: Still nope. :( The button looks like its pressing, but no code executes. I've used Web Inspector on the page and there isn't anything stopping the code, javascript is on in the phone, etc, etc.

Comment: May i suggest some alternative solution using jquery?

Comment: Absolutely! I'm happy to change the code around to get it be functional in some way for mobile.

Comment: Thank you, but now the buttons aren't even registering as "clicked" (before you could click them, and they'd show the difference in shading. Still, the rest of the script doesn't run.

I think it isn't may not be a problem with the click event, but somewhere in the rest of the code, because the click event isn't triggering anything (nor is onload.)

Comment: Perfect! In comparing the two in Web Inspector, I found the difference - it was the PAGE HEADERS. Of all things.
Thank you for your help! Its now working.